# How do I store the values entered into a for loop by a user?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < courses; i++) 
{
    cout << "Please Enter Letter Grade: ";
    cin >> grade1;

    cout << "Please Enter Course Weighting: ";
    cin >> weight1;
}
```

Now, lets say the loop runs 3 times and the values entered by the user for `grade1` and `weight1` are different each time. I want to store these different values so I can do some calculations with them.  How would I proceed to do so?

Comment: Use a fixed-length array, or a variable-length container like `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how use an array:

```
int grade[courses]; // this is an array with size of courses
double weight[courses];
for (int i = 0; i < courses; i++) {
    cout << "Please Enter Letter Grade: ";
    cin >> grade[i];

    cout << "Please Enter Course Weighting: ";
    cin >> weight[i];
}
```

Array is collection of data of the same type stored sequentially in computer memory. Syntax for array is as follow:

```
<type> <name>[<size>];
```

for example

```
int numberOfStudents[100];
```

is `int` array with maximum of 100 elements.

**H**ope **T**his **H**elps

Comment: It’s probably better to use allocated arrays than vla’s

Comment: @PaulRooney I agree but OP does not know even about arrays :) I can put it in there NP.

Answer (score 1):

group `grade` and `weight` into a [struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) and store them in a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

**code:**  (doesnt handle all potential errors)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct grade_weight
{
    int grade;
    int weight;
};

int main()
{
    int courses = 5;
    std::vector<grade_weight> result; 

    // potential optimization if you want
    //result.reserve(courses);   

    for (int i = 0; i < courses; i++) 
    {
        int grade, weight;

        std::cout << "Please Enter Letter Grade: ";
        std::cin >> grade;

        std::cout << "Please Enter Course Weighting: ";
        std::cin >> weight;

        result.push_back({grade, weight});
    }

    std::cout << "you input\n";
    for(auto& gw: result)
    {
        std::cout << "grade: " << gw.grade << ", weight: " << gw.weight << '\n'; 
    }
}
```